# How would I make the key to a json object the value of one of the items in said object?

Tags: python, json

Right now, an object in my .json file looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Bulbasaur",
    "type_1": "Grass",
    "type_2": "Poison",
    "primary_color": "Green",
    "height": 0.7,
    "weight": 6.9,
    "hp": 45,
    "attack": 49,
    "defense": 49,
    "speed": 45,
    "can_evolve": "TRUE",
    "evolves_from": "",
    "final_evolution": "FALSE",
    "mega_evolution": "FALSE"
},
```

I want a way to convert multiple (900 copies) of the json above, to this:

```
{
    "1": [
        {
            "name": "Bulbasaur",
            "type_1": "Grass",
            "type_2": "Poison",
            "primary_color": "Green",
            "height": 0.7,
            "weight": 6.9,
            "hp": 45,
            "attack": 49,
            "defense": 49,
            "speed": 45,
            "can_evolve": "TRUE",
            "evolves_from": "",
            "final_evolution": "FALSE",
            "mega_evolution": "FALSE"
        }
    ],
    "Bulbasaur": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "type_1": "Grass",
            "type_2": "Poison",
            "primary_color": "Green",
            "height": 0.7,
            "weight": 6.9,
            "hp": 45,
            "attack": 49,
            "defense": 49,
            "speed": 45,
            "can_evolve": "TRUE",
            "evolves_from": "",
            "final_evolution": "FALSE",
            "mega_evolution": "FALSE"
        }
    ]
}
```

Really I just need to find a way to make the key for an object the value of that same object, and i'll be all set.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need the elements of the results to be lists?

Comment: I guess not, I just need to get the same data with multiple keys, and this is the way I figured how to format it.

Comment: Could you simplify? I'm new to json

Comment: You only need a list if you have multiple values for each key. You don't need it with multiple keys for the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dict.fromkeys()`

```
original = {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Bulbasaur",
    "type_1": "Grass",
    "type_2": "Poison",
    "primary_color": "Green",
    "height": 0.7,
    "weight": 6.9,
    "hp": 45,
    "attack": 49,
    "defense": 49,
    "speed": 45,
    "can_evolve": "TRUE",
    "evolves_from": "",
    "final_evolution": "FALSE",
    "mega_evolution": "FALSE"
}

result = dict.fromkeys((original['id'], original['name']), original)
```

`result` is:

```
{1: {'attack': 49,
     'can_evolve': 'TRUE',
     'defense': 49,
     'evolves_from': '',
     'final_evolution': 'FALSE',
     'height': 0.7,
     'hp': 45,
     'id': 1,
     'mega_evolution': 'FALSE',
     'name': 'Bulbasaur',
     'primary_color': 'Green',
     'speed': 45,
     'type_1': 'Grass',
     'type_2': 'Poison',
     'weight': 6.9},
 'Bulbasaur': {'attack': 49,
               'can_evolve': 'TRUE',
               'defense': 49,
               'evolves_from': '',
               'final_evolution': 'FALSE',
               'height': 0.7,
               'hp': 45,
               'id': 1,
               'mega_evolution': 'FALSE',
               'name': 'Bulbasaur',
               'primary_color': 'Green',
               'speed': 45,
               'type_1': 'Grass',
               'type_2': 'Poison',
               'weight': 6.9}}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm assuming I can just run this for the id and name value?

Comment: I thought you wanted it for all values.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to do it with specific keys.

Comment: Yes yes yes you just saved me so much time. thank you so much!